# ¿Cómo puedo crear un checkbox que envie valores true o false?

Tags: html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, checkbox

estoy intentando hacer pruebas para enviar valores true o false mediante un checkbox a un método de mi controlador llamada: *ObtencionValores*, pero sinceramente, nada de lo que trato funciona. Siempre se envía false. ¿Alguien podría darme alguna idea?

HTML:

```
@using Proyecto.Models.Pruebas.PruebaModel;

<div class="bloque">
    <form asp-action="ObtencionValores" method="post">
        <div class="form-check form-switch">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" asp-for="ValorUno" id="boton" value="true">
            <label class="form-check-label">False</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check form-switch">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" asp-for="ValorDos" id="boton">
            <label class="form-check-label">True</label>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Enviar</button>
    </form>            
</div>
```

Modelo:

```
namespace Proyecto.Models.Pruebas
{
    public class PruebaModel
    {
        public bool ValorUno;
        public bool ValorDos;
    }
}
```

Método del controlador:

```
public IActionResult ObtencionValores(PruebaModel datosPrueba)
{
    Console.WriteLine(datosPrueba.ValorUno);
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Prueba");
}
```

Comment: Prueba colocar los `get;set;` por ejemplo `public bool ValorUno {get;set;}`

Comment: muchas gracias, sí funcionó eso 